# Removing --------- from choices in dropdown

Tags: django, django-forms

I believe that I may have implemented something that adds '-------' as a valid option in the drop downs that I have in my forms. Is there a setting in Django that I can change/remove/modify that will prevent '-------' from being an option that appears in one or all drop downs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your model form

```
column_name = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects, empty_label=None)
```

Comment: How would I set the queryset equal to a list of choices?

Comment: column_name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,empty_label=None)

Comment: plz be more specific ,if it won't works

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know. THanks so much Pranay.